# How to run Python functions within a C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a windows form application using C# but run existing python code within it. I currently have my entire program working in python code, but would like to use the functions I created in Python within my C# Windows Form Application. For example (keeping this very basic) let's say I have a label on my form called "label". Then I have a variable, x per say that's equal to 5. And a python functions that returns the string "True" if the passed in value is 5. Ideally I'd like to be able to say:

label.Text = PYTHONFUNCTION(x);

which would then run the python function and since x is 5 return the string "True" to the C# code and display it on the label. Is this at all possible, and if so how? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Possible variants: 1. IronPython is a .NET implementation. As I understand you can write a python code in IronPython and then just include the source in C# (not 100% sure).  2. Execute a python code as a command line. 3. Python creates a web site with REST API.